# Unable to import Chatterbot even after installing the chatterbot package through pip as well as on Pycharm through Python interpreter

Tags: python, installation, package, chatbot, chatterbot

**from ChatterBot import ChatBot**

C:\Users\Vishwakarma\PycharmProjects\FInal_chatbot\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Vishwakarma/PycharmProjects/FInal_chatbot/Final1.py

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Vishwakarma/PycharmProjects/FInal_chatbot/Final1.py", line 1, in 
    from ChatterBot import ChatBot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ChatterBot'**

Comment: Are you sure you installed the package in the correct env?

Comment: Yes, I guess. coz my other packages are working fine only problem is using the ChatterBot package.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this :

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
```

`chatterbot`  like most python packages is in lowercase.